# JSHint - ES6 configuration is not working in global

Tags: npm, sublimetext3, global, jshint, linter

Almost seven hours in a row, I tried everything, but it still does not want to work in a global mode with syntax es6 ~_~

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you found solution for this?

Comment: lol no, sublime - is a piece of shit, I switched to the VSCode and found it ULTRA awesome, endless customization - fast and EASY, and for free, my highly recommendations, mate ;)